# Remembering the selected tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I'm trying to figure out how to get jquery-tabs to remember which tab is was on when a form is submitted and redirected to a get.  I've found plenty of examples, but they all say to use `ui.index` in the `select` event, neither of which [is in the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate); I've confirmed that `ui.index` is not part of that object.  Using `$("#MyTabs").tabs("option", "selected")` in the `activate` event gets me the index of the tab that was previously selected, but not the tab the user just selected.  As in, if tab 0 is selected and I click on tab 3, I get 0, not 3.  I can't use the `active` option if I don't know the index.

Should I just count the list items in the unordered list that jquery is turning into the tabs, then use those to map from the div ID in `ui.newPanel`, or is there a more elegant way to do it?  Once I've got the right index, I'll probably add that to the query string.  The cookies solution doesn't sit right with me in case the user has multiple windows or browser tabs open.

**edit**: The problem is that the `active` option takes an index, but the `ui` parameter of the `activate` event only seems to give me the `li` and `div` elements for the tab and tab contents.  Since there used to be a `ui.index` property, I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

**edit**: Here's the solution I used with thanks to Kush; I omitted some code for brevity.

```
function Document_OnReady() {
    $("#MyTabs").tabs({
        active: $("input.InitialTabIndex").val()
    });

function SetInitialTab() {
    $("input.InitialTabIndex").val($("#MyTabs").tabs("option", "selected"));
}

function Form_OnSubmit() {
    SetInitialTab();
}
```

When the server handles the POST, I read the form value, then add it to the query string when I redirect to a get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden field. On click of any tab, keep the tab index on that hidden field, so next time it won't be problem for you to redirect the page. You can use the hidden field form element to redirect the page.

```
$('#hidden_field').val($tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'));
```

Comment: Thanks, Kush.  I wanted to see what "standard" practice was, but it doesn't look like there is one.  This is the best option from what I saw here in that it doesn't rely on things outside the API definition, but I'm not a jquery expert.  I ended up including the index in the query string after the redirect-to-get so that the user can take that URL, so long as I don't re-sequence the tabs!

Answer (score 1):

In general, the server-side code adds a class name to the selected element and spits out the page to the browser.

Comment: Diodeus, what server-side code?  If you mean client-side code, then yes, the class changes, but that still leaves me counting `li` tags to find the index that is selected.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: How do you process a form submission WITHOUT server-side code?

Comment: I am probably missing something in the jQuery Tabs API.  How do tell the API which class should indicate the initially active tab?  See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="selector" class="ui-mainColTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
</div>

<form id="form">
    <input type="submit" value="Kill" />
</form>

<a href="#" id="getCookie">Get</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selector").tabs({
        cookie: {
            name: 'tab_cookie',
            expires: 7
        }
    });


    $('#getCookie').click(function() {
        alert($.cookie('tab_cookie'));
    });

    $('#form').submit(function() {
        alert($.cookie('tab_cookie'));
    });
});
//-->
</script>
```

You need to add the jQuery cookie files from [**here**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Remembering data works with

```
jQuery.data('key', data);
```